# Python : Acces to className in a class method from the daughter class

Tags: python, inheritance, class-method, classname

My question is simple to pose I have that:

```
class A(object):
    def methodA():
        print(__class__)
class B(A):
    pass

B.methodA()
#<class '__main__.A'>
```

i would like to have class '**main**.B' without overwrite methodA in class B.

A can be a abstract class if it's help

Answer (score 1):

Use `@classmethod`:

```
In [5]: class A:
   ...:     @classmethod
   ...:     def foo(cls):
   ...:         print(cls)
   ...:
   ...:

In [6]: class B(A):
   ...:     pass
   ...:

In [7]:

In [7]: b = B()

In [8]: b.foo()
<class '__main__.B'>

In [9]: a = A()

In [10]: a.foo()
<class '__main__.A'>
```